# Shopify Webhook URL is called many times for same action

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I am using 'order/create' hook

it is created fine through app. but when order is placed , hook url is called from api many times.

Using php,  how i can make it call once only hook url.

I am sending response header of 200 ok also here is my api file code

$checkout_information   = json_decode(file_get_contents(

'php://input'));

```
        ob_start();
        print_r($_REQUEST);           
        print_r($checkout_information);   

        $out1 = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        mail('xxxx@xxx.com','Testing  Connect shopify order create',$out1);

        $status['status']    =    '200';

        http_response_code(200);
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        header("Status: 200 OK");
        echo json_encode($status);
        exit();
```

Any body to help me out in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

How long does your app take to return the 200? Shopify webhook docs state that they should get a response within 5 seconds, or they will retry.  Seems quite possible that sending an email may take more than 5 seconds.

Remember that you have to account for latency to/from Shopify in addition to your own processing.  I've seen them retry webhooks even with sub 2 second processing.

Ideally, you should place the webhook payload/topic on some sort of queue & perform any processing outside the HTTP request.

https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks